# ComboBoxRenderer cannot be converted to TableCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jtable, renderer

I try to create a combo box and add in my table column. I use this [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/CustomComboBoxDemoProject/src/components/CustomComboBoxDemo.java). When I try to do `col5.setCellRenderer(cmbRender);` it throws:

> "ComboBoxRenderer cannot be converted to TableCellRenderer".

ComboxRenderer

```
class ComboBoxRenderer extends JLabel
                           implements ListCellRenderer {
        private Font uhOhFont;

        public ComboBoxRenderer() {
            setOpaque(true);
            setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
            setVerticalAlignment(CENTER);
        }
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
                                           JList list,
                                           Object value,
                                           int index,
                                           boolean isSelected,
                                           boolean cellHasFocus) {

            int selectedIndex = ((Integer)value).intValue();

            if (isSelected) {
                setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
                setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
            } else {
                setBackground(list.getBackground());
                setForeground(list.getForeground());
            }
            String[] petStrings = {"Bird", "Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Pig"};
            String pet = petStrings[selectedIndex];
            setUhOhText(pet + " (no image available)",
            list.getFont());           
            return this;
        }
        protected void setUhOhText(String uhOhText, Font normalFont) {
            if (uhOhFont == null) { //lazily create this font
                uhOhFont = normalFont.deriveFont(Font.ITALIC);
            }
            setFont(uhOhFont);
            setText(uhOhText);
        }
    }
```

I try to call like this

```
         ComboBoxRenderer cmbRender = new ComboBoxRenderer();
         TableColumn col5 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
         col5.setCellRenderer(cmbRender);// give me error here
```

I want to create in my table column with value assigned in  the petString. Please advice.

This is how I do for TextBox

```
TextRenderer2 renderer2 = new TextRenderer2();
TableColumn col5 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
MyTableCellEditor editor = new MyTableCellEditor();
col5.setCellEditor(editor);
col5.setCellRenderer(renderer2);
col5.setPreferredWidth(100);
```

TextRenderer

```
class TextRenderer2 extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) 
        {
            JPanel jp_panel = new JPanel();

            JTextPane jta_text = new JTextPane();
            JScrollPane jsp_scroll = null;

            String valStr = value.toString();
            jta_text.setText(valStr);

            jp_panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            jsp_scroll = new JScrollPane(jta_text);
            jp_panel.add(jsp_scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            return jp_panel;
        }
    }
```

Comment: please whats goal, only to shows JComboBox in table cell as Renderer, decoreated JComboBox ....

Comment: @mKorbel i didnt get you. I want to create a drop down in my table column. For testing i just use petString to show in dropdown.

Comment: I hope that you understand renderers concept, renderer is only painting, nothing else, ListCellRenderer is for JList and JComboBox for JTable are there XxxTableCellRenderer/prepareRenderer, again whats goal, Question I want to create a drop down in my table column == TableCellEditor or not

Comment: @mKorbel Used renderer for display purpose and using TableCellEditor for holding the value. It works fine for my textbox and checkbox. Edited my answer with working textbox renderer.

Comment: why are you surprised - your ComboBoxRenderer implemens **List** CellRenderer while a table expects a **Table** CellRenderer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the implements ListCellRenderer to implements TableCellRenderer

```
class ComboBoxRenderer extends JComboBox implements TableCellRenderer {

        public ComboBoxRenderer(Object[] items) {
        super(items);
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (isSelected) {
            setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            super.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
            setForeground(table.getForeground());
            setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }
        // Select the current value
        setSelectedItem(value);
        return this;
    }
    }
```

Comment: you can do both: `ComboBoxRenderer implements ListCellRenderer, TableCellRenderer` :-)